# goapp serve: unable to find dev_appserver.py

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, go

using go 1.2 python 2.7 and appengine 1.8.9

`dev_appserver.py` works in dos box and is located in windows path.

`goapp.exe` also works in dos box and is located in windows path.

Any idea why `goapp.exe serve` does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`goapp/serve.go`](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/goapp/serve.go?r=a4936ec7ef0b33dfb91d500e07811df1d2e4a502&spec=svn9064906ca9cf52c538b6c9f8de6ce88ea0245fde#85) which produces this error message ("`unable to find dev_appserver.py`") shows the following code:

```
if p := os.Getenv("APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER"); p != "" {
  return p, nil
}
return "", fmt.Errorf("unable to find dev_appserver.py")
```

So double-check if, when using goapp, `APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER` environment variable was actually set.
See for instance this [`gotool.bat`](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/gotool.bat) script which *does* set that variable
(but [dsymonds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527967/dsymonds) rightly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198584/goapp-serve-unable-to-find-dev-appserver-py/21215399#comment41669424_21215399) that you should not set it directly, **you should always use `goapp`**):

```
@echo off
:: Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
:: Use of this source code is governed by the Apache 2.0
:: license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
setlocal
set GOROOT=%~dp0\goroot
set APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER=%~dp0\dev_appserver.py
set GOARCH=
set GOBIN=
set GOOS=

:: Set a GOPATH if one is not set.
if not "%GOPATH%"=="" goto havepath
set GOPATH=%~dp0\gopath
:havepath

%GOROOT%\bin\%~n0.exe %*
```

Comment: Damit why can't they include it in the error message :) "APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER env not set correctly"

Comment: Don't set APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER. Use goapp from the top of the SDK, not the one buried under goroot/bin.

Comment: @dsymonds you are right. I didn't meant for the user to set `APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER` himself, simply to check if it was set. I have rephrase the answer, and included your comment.